# How to determine if JDK8 lambda can be assigned to type?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

**Edit**: this question is malformed to the extent that I cannot really fix it, and is a bug somewhere in my project. The root cause of my problem is that myLambda.getClass() should not throw ClassNotFoundException, and the lambda works as expected.

Given the class of an interface

```
Class myIf = MyIf.class;
```

And a lambda instance

```
Object myLambda;
```

How can I determine if myLambda can be assigned to MyIf without throwing an exception ? This is a bit puzzling since myLambda.getClass() throws an exception. And the "obvious"

```
myIf.isInstance(myLambda)
```

returns false

Comment: Sorry; I was slightly ambigious in the question; i edited it now. I have the Class of the interface

Comment: Which exception? Stack trace please.

Comment: myLambda.getClass() throws ClassNotFoundException

Comment: That's not a stack trace.

Comment: `myIf.isInstance(myLambda)` returns false, means `Object` is not  assignment-compatible with `MyIf`, because `Object` is not a sub-class of `MyIf`, meaning: you can do `Object X = myIf;` but you cannot do `MyIf Y = myObject;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct me again if my assumptions were incorrect, but you would do it as you normally would

```
static Class<?> clazz = MyIf.class;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    method(() -> System.out.println("hello")); // lambda

}

public static void method(MyIf myIf) { 
    System.out.println(clazz.isAssignableFrom(myIf.getClass()));
}

static interface MyIf {
    public void execute();
}
```

prints

```
true
```

You don't actually ever get a reference to the lambda expression, the compiler generates a (synthetic?) class and an instance of it is passed to your method.

Comment: Where is your lambda instance ?

Comment: `() -> System.out.println("hello")`

Comment: @krosenvold Bound to the parameter `myIf` in `method(MyIf)`.

Comment: W00t; there appears to be some kind of corner case here. Your code works :)

Comment: @krosenvold You should post something reproducible. Can only guess otherwise.

Comment: @krosenvold I want to go to bed, it's 3 a.m. But I want to see this more.

Comment: The problem is something totally different, myLambda.getClass() should not throw ClassNotFoundException

Comment: @krosenvold Couldn't reproduce it? Or is it too large of an example to fit here?